# linux bash week number of year iso-8601

Tags: php, linux, date, iso8601

How can I print equal in linux bash with linux date command like in php:

> php -r 'echo date("o.W");'

I found in %V in linux bash but,

my first problem is:

> %V   Week number of year with Monday as first day of week (01..53)
>          If the week containing January 1 has four or
>          more days in the new year, then it is considered week 1;
>          otherwise, it is week 53 of the previous year, and the next week
>          is week 1. **Similar to ISO 8601 (but not 100% compliant.)**

and my secound problem, i didn't found similar option like "o" in php.

Answer (score 0):

you can use %G%V for ISO Year and ISO Week standard, or %Y,%W for %Y,%U calendar weeks.

check FORMAT controls of the linux date command:

```
 > man date
   ...
   %G     year of ISO week number (see %V); normally useful only with %V
   %V     ISO week number, with Monday as first day of week (01..53)

   %Y     Year YYYY
   %U     week number of year, with Sunday as first day of week (00..53)
   %W     week number of year, with Monday as first day of week (00..53)

 > date --date "01 Jan 2022" "+%G/%V"
 2021/52
```